# Click : options of first command not usable after using CommandCollection()

Tags: python, python-click

I want to have two separate sub-commands, each with different options.

E.g. -

```
command first --one --two
command second --three
```

The options `one` and `two` are just for sub-command `first` and `three` for sub-command `second`.

My code is of the form:

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--one')
@click.option('--two') 
def cli1():
 print("clione")
@cli1.command()
def first():
   pass

@click.group()
@click.option('--three')
def cli2():
 print("clitwo")
@cli2.command()
def second():
   pass

cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[cli1, cli2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
     cli()
```

But after running it, I'm not able to run any of the options for each sub-command.

I used this : [Merging Multi Commands](http://click.pocoo.org/5/commands/#merging-multi-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest way to do sub-commands is to only use one group, and I usually name that group `cli` like:

```
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass
```

Using the name of the group, declare commands like:

```
@cli.command()
def name_of_command():
    ....
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.option('--one')
@click.option('--two')
def first(one, two):
    click.echo("clione %s %s" % (one, two))

@cli.command()
@click.option('--three')
def second(three):
    click.echo("clitwo %s" % three)

cli('first --one 4'.split())
```

#### Results

```
clione 4 None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Why did making different groups did not work? :)

Comment: Your code had more than one issue.  But the biggest was that you were adding the options to the group and not to the command.